# Recursion and bissection search to find character: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am currently trying to learn Python 3 through **MITx: 6.00.1x Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python**, and I got stuck in the following exercise (kind of):

> We can use the idea of bisection search to determine if a character is in a string, so long as the string is sorted in alphabetical order.
>
> First, test the middle character of a string against the character you're looking for (the "test character"). If they are the same, we are done - we've found the character we're looking for!
>
> If they're not the same, check if the test character is "smaller" than the middle character. If so, we need only consider the lower half of the string; otherwise, we only consider the upper half of the string. (Note that you can compare characters using Python's < function.)
>
> Implement the function isIn(char, aStr) which implements the above idea recursively to test if char is in aStr. char will be a single character and aStr will be a string that is in alphabetical order. The function should return a boolean value.

My code is the following:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    '''
    char: a single character
    aStr: an alphabetized string

    returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
    '''
# makes the string and character lower case and removes special characters from string
def lower_string(char, aStr):
    aStr = aStr.lower()
    char = char.lower()
    ans = ""
    for i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        if i in aStr:
            ans += i
        return ans

def isInTrue(char, aStr):
    if char == aStr[len(aStr)//2]:
        return True
    elif len(aStr) == 1 and char != aStr:
        return False
    elif len(aStr) == 1 and char == aStr:
        return True
    elif len(aStr) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        if char > aStr[len(aStr)//2]:
            return isInTrue(char, aStr[len(aStr)//2:])
        else:
            return isInTrue(char,aStr[:len(aStr)//2])

return isInTrue(lower_string(char, aStr))
```

I created a more simple version of this code, too, because the code above wouldn't run:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    '''
    char: a single character
    aStr: an alphabetized string

    returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
    '''
    if len(aStr) == 0:
        return False
    elif len(aStr) == 1 and char != aStr:
        return False
    elif len(aStr) == 1 and char == aStr:
        return True
    elif char == aStr[len(aStr)//2]:
        return True
    else:
        if char > aStr[len(aStr)//2]:
            return isIn(char, aStr[len(aStr)//2:])
        else:
            return isIn(char, aStr[:len(aStr)//2])
```

My issue is:

If I run the first, more complex, code with **char = "o"** and **aStr = "abcdefopq"**, I get the error: **isInTrue() missing 1 required positional argument: 'aStr'**. I don't understand why this happens; I have checked the code several times and failed to find what's missing (but this is surely my fault).

The second, more simple, code works as expected.

If someone could explain me what's wrong in my code, I'd be very thankful. I have spent at least two hours on this problem, and I am starting to question whether Python (or programming in general) is meant for me.

Thanks.

Comment: `isInTrue` takes two parameters and you called it with only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @interjay mentioned you are calling `isInTrue` with one instead of two arguments.

```
return isInTrue(lower_string(char, aStr))
               ( -   one argument     - )
```

Solution 1: 
We alter `lower_string()`, such that it only returns the lower-case-version of `aStr`.

```
def lower_string(aStr):
    aStr = aStr.lower()
    ans = ""
    for i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        if i in aStr:
            ans += i
    return ans
```

And you can call it with

```
return isInTrue(char.lower(), lower_string(aStr))
```

---

Solution 2: We alter `lower_string()` slightly, so that it will return a tuple of both lower-case-versions.

```
def lower_string(char, aStr):
    aStr = aStr.lower()
    ans2 = char.lower()
    ans1 = ""
    for i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
        if i in aStr:
            ans += i
    return (ans1, ans2)
```

And you can call it with

```
return isInTrue(*lower_string(char, aStr))
```

Here is a minimal example of 'Solution 2'. The `return`-value of `foo` is a `tuple` and the asterisk-operator (*) unpacks this tuple.

```python
def foo(a,b):
    return (a,b)

def bar(c,d):
    print(c)
    print(d)

bar(*foo(3,4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSEtP18jUSdJ04pLAQiKUktKi/IUwCJcXCD5pMQijWSdFKh8QVFmXolGsiYSJwWoEKRIC2SSsY6Jpub//wA)

---

edit: Don't give up on programming after only two hours. Writing code often means to write for an hour and to debug for several hours. One of the best ways to debug is to write your code as minimal as possible. For instance, try to reproduce your error using my minimal example above.  ([Here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSEtP18jUSdJ04pLAQiKUktKi/IUErm4QHJJiUUayTopULmCosy8Eo1kTSROiiYXF0gRyBBjHRNNTa7//wE) is the solution - click on >debug to see the output.)

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the specifics of your code, I know it's tedious to understand recursion from the first glance. You should think of recursion as a sophisticated way to repeat things like in a `while loop` by calling functions repeatedly:

```
def isln(char, aStr):
        while aStr:
            mid_char_index = (len(aStr) // 2)
            mid_char = aStr[mid_char_index]

            if mid_char == char:
                return True
            elif char < mid_char: 
                aStr = aStr[:mid_char_index]     # lower half of string
            else:
                aStr = aStr[mid_char_index + 1:]  # upper half of string without mid_char
        else:
            return False
```

We arrived to this point now. How to make that in recursion? It should be easier now:

```
def isln(char, aStr):
    if aStr:
        mid_char_index = (len(aStr) // 2)
        mid_char = aStr[mid_char_index]

        if mid_char == char:
            return True
        elif char < mid_char: 
            return isln(char, aStr[:mid_char_index])     # lower half of string
        else:
            return isln(char, aStr[mid_char_index + 1:])  # upper half of string without mid_char
    else: 
            return False

isln("e", "abcdefg")
```

The main thing is to understand the question first and then code and finally tailor your code if it can be tailored. You second code is close to what the question is asking:

> char will be a single character and aStr will be a string that is in alphabetical order.

I take "order" as an ordered string argument. So I didn't  sort `aStr` in `isln`.  The question didn't ask explicitly for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point it out that `so long as the string is sorted in alphabetical order` may not mean that `aStr` will always come sorted for your code to test upon.

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    aStr = ''.join(sorted(aStr))

    if aStr == '':
        return False
    if len(aStr) == 1:
        return char == aStr

    if char == aStr[len(aStr)//2]:
        return True
    elif char < aStr[len(aStr)//2]:
        aStr = aStr[0: len(aStr)//2]
    elif char > aStr[len(aStr)//2]:
        aStr = aStr[len(aStr)//2+1: len(aStr)]

    return isIn(char, aStr)
```